# How can I make a Select statement to Order By an equation? (To order by shortest distance)

Tags: android, sqlite, select, location, equation

I'm working on an application that needs to display the nearest hotels (for example) to the user's location. A SQLite database contains all hotels along with their Longitudes and Latitudes. I searched and found that the easiest way to do this is to write a certain equation in the "Order By" in the select statement.

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_Hotel, hotelsNames, null, null, null, null, ((lat - Double.valueOf(hotelsLat[0].trim()).doubleValue()) * (lat - Double.valueOf(hotelsLat[0].trim()).doubleValue()) +
            (lon - Double.valueOf(hotelsLong[0].trim()).doubleValue()) * (lon - Double.valueOf(hotelsLong[0].trim()).doubleValue()));
```

Note: The hotelsLong and hotelsLat are String[] containing the longitudes and latitudes from the database.

This is the select statement I made, the problem is that there is an error that says that the select statement's parameters must be (String, String[], String, String[], String, String, String) but what I've done is (String, String[], null, null, null, null, ***double***)

How should I do it? and how will it order the results by the equation's results?

Comment: oehm, the direct distance between two points can be way shorter then the "street - distance" so you might get cases where you send the user to a more distant. Oh and the Google Maps Api has a function to get the distance between two points

Comment: This may locate the closest hotels (in absolute terms), but not necessarily the easiest ones to reach (consider, for instance, a user on one side of a long, narrow lake, and a hotel on the opposite side)

Comment: But, in this part, I don't want to display my results on a map. The idea is that I have like a search page where he chooses what he wants to search and the results are displayed in a list view with the nearest result on top and the furthest result is at the end of the list

Answer (score 0):

First, your distance calculation seems incorrect. See source of [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class for [distanceBetween()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/location/Location.java#Location.distanceBetween%28double,double,double,double,float%5B%5D%29) method. I advise you to use this or [distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) of the same class.

About the adapter to use. `CursorAdapter` is used if your data comes from database, otherwise some descendant of `BaseAdapter` is used. You have two options. Save the current distance in the sql table as a new column (everytime the new location is received or the user defined a location to search) and than sorting by it or use the `ArrayAdapter` for your `ListView`.

I'll describe the 2nd option, which should be smoother if hotels are being displayed according to the user location and location updates are quite frequent as it doesn't access database everytime new location is received, but on the other hand it consumes more memory because hotels are stored as objects:

Create `AsyncTask` to get a `Cursor` containing hotels. Traverse cursor and fill a list of hotels:

```
@Override
protected List<Hotel> doInBackground(Void... unused) {
    final Cursor c = database.query(getting hotels);
    if (c == null) {
        return null;
    }
    List<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<Hotel>();
    try {
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
            hotel.fillFromCursor(c); // fills data from cursor
            hotels.add(hotel);
        }
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
    return hotels;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Hotels> hotels) {
    if (hotels != null) {
        mHotelsAdapter.clear();
        for (Hotel h : hotels) {
            mHotelsAdapter.add(h);
        }
        // mLocation is our current location, if we have one, set the distance, see below
        mHotelsAdapter.updateDistance(mLocation);
    }
}
```

mHotelsAdapter is an adapter for your ListView. Adapter contains `updateDistance()` method which should be called everytime the desired location is changed (like in `onLocationChanged(Location location)` of your LocationListener). The method updates the distance and sorts items.

```
mHotelsAdapter = new HotelAdapter(this);
getListView().setAdapter(mHotelsAdapter);
...

public class HotelsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Hotel> {
    ...
    public void updateDistance(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
                Hotel hotel = getItem(i);
                hotel.setDistance(location);
             }
             sort(mComparator);
             notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // implement getView
    }

    private static final Comparator<Hotel> mComparator = new Comparator<Hotel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Hotel lhs, Hotel rhs) {
            if (lhs.getDistance() > rhs.getDistance()) {
                return 1;
            } else if (lhs.getDistance() < rhs.getDistance()) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

and finally here is the `setDistance()` method of the `Hotel` class, which sets the distance of the hotel to the location given as a parameter:

```
public void setDistance(Location location) {
    float results[] = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(),
        getLatitude(), getLongitude(), results);
    mDistance = results[0];
}
```